# No module named xblock.fields on installing edX platform

Tags: python, mongodb, edx

Im on installing edX platform using this instructions ( http://nkokkos.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/setting-up-edx-platform-on-ubutnu/ ),
I followed; every step successfully, but on `./manage.py lms syncdb –migrate`, I face to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 90, in <module>
    startup = importlib.import_module(edx_args.startup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/peyman/dev/edx/lms/startup.py", line 9, in <module>
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS  # pylint: disable=W0104
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'lms.envs.dev' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named xblock.fields
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No, I couldn't handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here for trouble with Open edX installation, try this latest guide instead of the one linked above:
http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

i checked the code accordingly in your edx-platform folder structure, look for lms\envs\ there many environment file for migration exists